# Call to a member function fetch() on boolean (xampp)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Help me please. PHP returned me error 'Call to a member function fetch() on boolean'`

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("select id,name,biography from authors where id=?");
$data = array($_POST['id']);
$result = $sql->execute($data);
$str=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
```

The query was made successfully because
var_dump($result)=bool(true).

The same result I have with:
    `$sql = $pdo->prepare("select id,name,biography from authors where   id=:id");
    $result = $sql->execute(array(':id'=>$_POST['id']));
    $str=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Query

`$pdo->query("select id,name,biography from authors");`

was made successful

Answer (score 0):

`execute()` returns true or false, thats why you get the error. You should fetch results something like this:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("select id,name,biography from authors where id= ?");
$data = array($_POST['id']);
$sql->execute($data);
$str=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```